# First time creating Stack.One line is printing twice.Why?

Tags: c, pointers

I have updated the previous code as you said but there is one last problem.
I don't know why there is a line which keeps on printing twice when I run the code.

And the line is:

```
printf("\nEnter values of x:");
```

And the code is:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
  int a;
 struct node* next;
}node;

node* create(node* s)
{
  s=NULL;
  printf("\n Empty stack is created\n");
  return s;
}

node* insert(node* s,int x)
{
  if (s==NULL)
  {
  s=malloc(sizeof(node));
  s->a=x;
  s->next=NULL;
  }

  else
  {
    node* temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->a=x;
    temp->next=s;
    s=temp;
  }
  return s;
}
node* print(node* s)
{
  while(s!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d",s->a);
    s=s->next;
  }
  return s;
}
node* delete(node* s)
{
  node* s1;
  if(s==NULL)
  {
  printf("trying to delete from empty list");
  }
  else
  {
   s1=s->next;
   printf("element deleted is %d",s->a);
   s->next=NULL;
   free(s);
   }
  return s1;
}
node* delete(node*s);
node* insert(node*s,int x);
node* create(node* s);
node* print(node* s);
int main()
{
node* top;
top=create(top);
char x;
int val;
while(1)
{

  printf("\nEnter values of x:");
  scanf("%c",&x);
  switch(x)
  {
  case 'I':
  {
    printf("\nPlease enter value to be inserted\n");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    top=insert(top,val);
    break;
  }
  case 'D':
  {
    delete(top);
    break;
  }
  case 'P':
  {
    top=print(top);
  }
  case 'E':
  {
      return 0;
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct {`  You need tag name.--> `typedef struct  node {`

Comment: @Debug obviously i tried to find error,but failed to do so thats why i asked here :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thnx sir code worked i just did what you said but instead if i write typedef struct list(or any other name) ,then i am still getting the same error.why?

Comment: Because it shows (anonymous or) another structure.

Comment: `tagless` or `with no tag`. Definitely no the anonymous.

Comment: example of _anonymous structure_ 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers p19 EXAMPLE 1.

Comment: thnx sir i got it i have just updated the code can you please tell me why the  given line is printing twice after first time.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but probably `scanf("%c",&x);` The second time this receive a newline. --> `scanf(" %c",&x);`

Comment: In SO, you should not change such a question. This is because the existing answer will not make sense. Please make another question.

Answer (score 0):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
 struct node* next;
}node;
```

there are declared two types. The first one is an unnamed structure type that gets the typedef name `node`. The second one is the incomplete `struct node` declared within the unnamed structure.

As result for example in this statement in the function `insert`

```
temp->next=s;
```

there is an attempt to assign a pointer of the type `node` that is `s`  to a pointer of the type `struct node` that is `temp->next` and there is no implicit conversion from one pointer to another.

You should rewrite the typedef the following way

```
typedef struct node {
  int a;
 struct node* next;
}node;
```

In this case the names `struct node` and `node` refer to the same entity.

Pay attention to that this function

```
node* create(node* s)
{
  s=NULL;
  printf("\n Empty stack is created");
  return s;
}
```

does not make sense, In fact the parameter is redundant. You can just write

```
node* create( void )
{
  printf("\n Empty stack is created");
  return NULL;
}
```

or

```
void create(node **s)
{
  *s = NULL;
  printf("\n Empty stack is created");
}
```

Also this function

```
node* delete(node* s)
{
  node* s1;
  if(s==NULL)
  {
  printf("trying to delete from empty list");
  }
  else
  {
   s1=s->next;
   printf("element deleted is %d",s->a);
   s->next=NULL;
   free(s);
   }
  return s1;
}
```

has undefined behavior because it return uninitialized pointer `s1` when `s` is equal to `NULL`.

And you have to use the return value of the function delete that is this call

```
delete(top);
```

is incorrect because the original pointer `top` was not changed.

Comment: thnx i got it but now there is one last problem.Can you please see the updated code :)

Comment: @codie It is a bad idea to change the original question entirely because this will confuse readers o the question and answers. It is better to ask a new question.

Comment: @codie As for your new question then use a blank before format conversion scanf(" %c",&x);

Comment: thank you sir error is fixed but can you please explain what was the problem.

Comment: @codie The function reads all character including new line characters if the blank is absent. So the function read the character that corresponds to the entered Enter key.

Comment: ok sir.I guess it has something related to buffer.You mean the Enter key was got stored in computers memory and scanf read it.right? I used fflush(stdin) and I guess it is also used to clear buffer but it is not working.why?

Comment: @codie fflush( stdin ) has undefined behavior.